# Maven Wrapper not working on Windows OS

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I always use a Mac at work and build my Spring and Spring Boot apps using command line and using maven installed. So normally I write:

```
mvn clean install
```

Now I was using my girlfriend Windows PC and I don't want to install maven on it. My idea was to use the maven wrapper provided by Spring initializer when you open a new project from IntelliJ IDEA CE.

I've tried many combinations by the command line windows within IntelliJ but the command is always not recognized. 
What am I getting wrong?

I've tried:

```
./mvnw clean
./mvn clean
mvnw.cmd clean
./mvnw.cmd clean
```

but with no results at all. I attach the image of the project with the maven wrapper folder opened to show its contents.
[image]

Comment: You are trying to use unix/mac command in Windows which doesn't work. You need to directly run `mvnw.cmd` for example.

Comment: I get this: C:\Users\DeboraPC\Downloads\demoRossini>mvnw.cmd
'mvnw.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to descend one more directory level down from what I can tell in your screenshot.

```
cd C:\Users\DeboraPC\Downloads\demoRossini\demoRossini
mvnw clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows cmd `"mvnw clean test"` worked
In Intellij terminal `".\mvnw clean test"` worked

I hope that helps.